# animate on scroll does not work on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make my section1 animate on scroll. But it doesn't seem to work, which confuses me, since I've already used this scroll code on another element, which works fine. That element, however, does not start off screen.

Here's my code.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
//section1
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( ( scrollPos > 150 ) && ( scrollState === 'top' ) ) {
        $("#section1").animate({left: '60'}, 700);
        scrollState = 'scrolled';
    }    
});
```

```css
#section1 {
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 3em;
 margin-bottom: 3em; 
 font-size: 1em;
 height: auto;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 left: -60em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <p>blablablablablablablabla </p> 
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `scrollState` to `top`?

Comment: That way the length scrolled is messured from the top, or so I would think.

Comment: But where is the declaration he's asking.

Comment: Sorry. It's declared further up in the code:                                                    var scrollState = 'top';
//rowheader
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( ( scrollPos > 150 ) && ( scrollState === 'top' ) ) {
        $("#rowheader h1").animate({left: '-20em'}, 700);
        scrollState = 'scrolled';
    }       
    else if( ( scrollPos <= 150 ) && ( scrollState === 'scrolled' ) ) {
        $("#rowheader h1").animate({left: '0'}, 500);
        scrollState = 'top';
    }
});

Comment: btw, that code work's just fine, which is why I don't get what's wrong

Comment: Are you trying to make the section1 slide in when the user has scrolled 150px down the page?

Comment: Try add just one window.scroll

Comment: Yes. As you can see in the css it starts off the screen (left: -30em). However the scroll doesn't work. It does work for the rowheader though

Comment: @P. Frank, if I use just one window scroll, how do I add the section1-part? As an else if?

Comment: If is in same page please see my update. Want you detect scroll inside your element section1 and rowheader?

Answer (score 0):

I not understand exactly what you want, but if you use a container without scrollbar or just you want detect when user scroll, You can use `DOMMouseScroll` for detect when scroll. This work fine. Please try below:

```js
$('html').on ('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.detail  < 0) {
      $("#section1").animate({left: '-60em'}, 700);
    } else {
      $("#section1").animate({left: '60'}, 700);
    }
});
```

```css
#section1 {
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 3em;
 margin-bottom: 3em; 
 font-size: 1em;
 height: auto;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 left: -60em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="section1" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <p>blablablablablablablabla </p> 
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

You have two window.scroll function who make same things. You can join two:

```
var main = function() {

    var scrollState = 'top';
    //rowheader
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 

        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if( ( scrollPos > 150 ) && ( scrollState === 'top' ) ) {
            $("#rowheader h1").animate({left: '-20em'}, 700);
            $("#section1").animate({left: '60'}, 700);
            scrollState = 'scrolled';
        }       
        else if( ( scrollPos <= 150 ) && ( scrollState === 'scrolled' ) ) {
            $("#rowheader h1").animate({left: '0'}, 500);
            scrollState = 'top';
        }
    });

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, one thing that might not be working for you is that you after 150px might have scrolled the section out of view. In this case you should use a fixed position or define a top distance.

Secondly I would recommend that you use CSS for defining the visibility of the element rather than jQuery or javascript.

Please check out this fiddle for a demo with fixed position on the section element. https://jsfiddle.net/cazdt0gj/

By adding classes you don't have to worry about "the scrolled" part of your code as well.

```
$("#section1").addClass('active')
```